# Postach.io and google-code-prettify

Tags: google-code-prettify

Is there a way to use markdown and google-code-prettify library to use together to pretify the my code?

I have been using

```
        var s = "hello world!";
   ```

which produces <pre><code> </code></pre> HTML markup. But I am unable to add the prettyprint class to it.

I have also tried using basic html markup

<pre class="prettyprint"><code> var s = "hello world!"; </code></pre>

but postach.io seems to remove the pre and code html tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by adding the following lines to the *head* section of the html template using source editor of postach.io

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.exports = { 
        activate : function (a,b,c) {
            $("pre").addClass("prettyprint linenums");
            PR.prettyPrint();
        }
    }
</script>

<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js?autoload=true&callback=activate"></script>
```

and my markdown code is

```
´´´ var s = "hello world!";  ´´´
```